# C++ r-value reference in C terms?

Tags: c++, c, move, rvalue-reference

I don't know whether I am asking a good question, but I am really curious about this. Everything except for this new r-value reference introduced in C++, I can translate and understand in C terms. Not everyone would agree with me but to me, C++ is a highly sophisticated C macro extension.

Okay, what I want to know here is that, for example if you look at constructors and destructors as follows,

```
{
    struct Object {
        char* s;
        Object(size_t n) { s = new char[n]; }
        ~Object() { delete[] s; }
    } o(10);
}
```

you can expect the compiler to handle the code as if,

```
{
    struct Object { char* s; } o;
    new_Object(&o, 10); /* o->s = malloc(10); */
    delete_Object(&o); /* free(o->s); */
}
```

I'm not saying the C++ compiler has to do this translation. I just believe that C++ was designed to work this way, in order to integrate smoothly with existing C applications and attract C developers.

Anyway, a plain l-value reference can be understood as, and is most likely to actually be, an abstracted pointer. To the compiler it should be same with,

```
int n = 1;
int& m = n;
m = 2;
```

and

```
int n = 1;
int* m = &n;
*m = 2;
```

But what about r-value references? Can anyone explain how r-value references and `std::move` could be understood in C terms?

Comment: An rvalue reference has the same internal representation as an lvalue reference - most often, a pointer. The difference between the two is not in how they are represented, but in what you can assume about the object they point to. In other words, the nature of the reference affects overload resolution performed in expressions involving it.

Comment: To elaborate on what Igor said, C selects a function based on name, C++03 based on name and argument types and cv-qualification (except that pass-by-value ignores top level cv-qualification), and C++11 and later based on name, argument types, argument cv qualification, and argument value categories.  (Object type, cv-qualification, and value category become part of the composite type)

Comment: I think for the sake of your future understanding it's better to not equate everything with C terms because they are, ultimately, different languages going in different directions.

Comment: Like Rapptz already pointed out the languages are totally different. Translating c++ into c often times easy because c is largely a subset of c++. Sure, you can express every concept from c++ in c because c is Turing complete. But so is LaTeX. C++ is an extension of c the same way C++ is an extension of LaTeX. They are different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same as an lvalue reference except that it can only bind to rvalues.

An example might be:

```
typedef struct S { int x; } S;
S foo() { S s; return s; }
S && r = foo();
```

C equivalent of the last line might be:

```
S *p = &(foo());
```

except that C has a rule that you cannot apply `&` to rvalues , and also that the return value of a function call does not persist past the end of the statement with the function call.

So you would have to write something like:

```
S temp = foo();
S *p = &temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
a         // this is an lvalue - you can assign to it
(a + b)   // this is an rvalue - you cannot assign to it
&a        // this is a kind of lvalue reference - a pointer
&(a + b)  // so this would be an rvalue reference, if C supported it
```

Rvalue references allow you represent the intermediate results of expressions and additionally know that these results are temporary (rvalues), so they will not be used any further.

If you receive let's say `std::vector<int>` as an rvalue reference parameter to a function, you know that it will be destructed right after the function returns, so if you want to store its contents you can just use `swap`. This is not possible with lvalue references - the vector could still be used after your function returns and you would break something.

If you are faimilar with `std::auto_ptr`, then rvalue references are pretty similar to passing `std::auto_ptr` by value as a parameter, which expresses the semantics of "callee takes responsibility of deleting the passed object". The main difference is that the compiler will automatically create rvalue references for you if you pass the results of non-lvalue expressions to functions.

`std::move` allows you to create an rvalue reference from something that would ordinarily be an lvalue reference. It essentially says "I'm not going to use this anymore, callee can do whatever it wants with this".